# How to access information in Sails after creation?

Tags: sails.js

I was wondering what happens in Sails when you pass information in through the URL. For example, if you were to type:

localhost:1337/project/create?Id=2&Name=John

how does Sails create that into a model? I need to be able to take the name and pass it to separate database, but I have no idea how to access the information (such as name=John, in this case) after each creation.

Thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your api/models/project.js file you can override afterCreate method like doc say :

```
afterCreate: fn(newlyInsertedRecord, cb)
```

More here : http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html